# Transcendental functions generating almost integers

Tags: approximation-theory, diophantine-approximation, transcendental-number-theory

Informally speaking, an "almost integer" is a real number very close to an integer.

There are some known ways to construct such examples in a systematic way. One is through the use of certain algebraic numbers called Pisot numbers. These numbers $\alpha$ have the property that their powers can get arbitrarly close to integers, that is:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha - [\alpha^n] = 0$

where $[ .]$ is the nearest integer function.

A well-known exanmple is given by the golden ratio $\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$, whose powers are increasingly close to integers:

$\varphi^{19} = 9349.000107...$

$\varphi^{25} = 167761.00000596...$

Another example comes from numbers of the form $e^{\pi\sqrt{n}}$.

A well-known example is Ramanujan's constant:

$e^{\pi\sqrt{163}} = 262537412640768743.99999999999925007...$

There's another interesting way to generate almost integers by using the numbers $e$ and $\pi$. By using the identity

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2x}=x^{-1/2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi n^2/x}.$$

we can derive the approximate identity:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{e^{-\frac{k^2\pi}{n}}}\approx\frac{1+\sqrt{n}}{2}$$

which provides a way to construct almost integers with increasing precision:

$ e^{-\frac{\pi}{9}} + e^{-4\frac{\pi}{9}} + e^{-9\frac{\pi}{9}} + e^{-16\frac{\pi}{9}} + e^{-25\frac{\pi}{9}} + e^{-36\frac{\pi}{9}} + e^{-49\frac{\pi}{9}} + e^{-64\frac{\pi}{9}} = 1.0000000000010504... $

$\sum_{k=1}^{24} e^{-k^2\frac{\pi}{25}} = 2.000000000000000000000000000000000310793...$

$\sum_{k=1}^{48} e^{-k^2\frac{\pi}{49}} = 3.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000838654...$

So, I wonder: is there another way to generate almost integers -with or without increasing precision- by using transcendental functions, as in the previous example?

Comment: Take a convergent series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$, its limit $x$, and consider numbers $\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=1}^nx_k$. At any rate, I think this question would be better suited for [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A little-known fact is that $e^{-\pi \sqrt{163}}$ is also close to an integer.

Comment: Now posted to m.se, without notification to either site, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131986/transcendental-functions-and-almost-integers – please don't do that.